# Best keyboard discipline mechanism for TextInput which is followed by ScrollView?

Tags: react-native

I have something like (chat app like interface)

```
<View>
    <View>
        <ScrollView/>
    </View>
    <TextInput/>
</View>
```

I did refer this helpful article [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/how-to-make-your-react-native-app-respond-gracefully-when-the-keyboard-pops-up-7442c1535580#.uzayahxwd). How ever virtual keyboard still obscures(overlaps, renders on top of) the TextInput (and the ScrollView). (Targeting both android and iOS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure I understood your question, but what I think you want is to prevent the keyboard from being on top of the TextInput.

To solve this problem you can use something called `[KeyboardAvoidingView][1]` which comes with React Native. You can try to solve your problem using one of these methods:

1-Replace the main View with a `KeyboardAvoidingView`

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={"padding"}>
    <View>
        <ScrollView/>
    </View>
    <TextInput/>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

2-Or, put the TextInput inside a KeyboardAvoidingView.

```
<View>
    <View>
        <ScrollView/>
    </View>
    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={"padding"}
       <TextInput/>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</View>
```

to import it use: `import {View, TextInput, ScrollView, KeyboardAvoidingView} from 'react-native'`

Cheers!

Comment: 1. Doesn't work
2. Doesn't work and disturbs the UI by adding unwanted spaces.

Comment: Did you check the example in this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html)?

Comment: Please take a look at [this example I made](https://rnplay.org/apps/8buY0A)

Comment: Also please note that the prop for the `KeyboardAvoidingView` is "behavior" not "behaviour," maybe this caused it not to work (My bad)

Comment: Your attempt for the solution is well appreciated. But this solution doesn't respect the existing CSS.